# Query regarding javascript document.getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript

So there is two time tag with different class name "u-dt" and "latestDate u-dt" respectively.
I am triying document.getElementsByClassName().innerhtml to select class "u-dt" to print 20 minutes ago only , but it is also putting out 38 minutes ago form "latestDate u-dt" class which is 38 minutes and i don't want that, I only want that 20 minutes ago form "u-dt" class.

```
<time class="u-dt" dir="auto" datetime="2020-01-18T11:04:03+0530" data-time="1579325643" data-date-string="Jan 18, 2020" data-time-string="11:04 AM" title="Jan 18, 2020 at 11:04 AM">20 minutes ago</time>
```

```
<time class="latestDate u-dt" dir="auto" datetime="2020-01-18T10:47:10+0530" data-time="1579324630" data-date-string="Jan 18, 2020" data-time-string="10:47 AM" title="Jan 18, 2020 at 10:47 AM">38 minutes ago</time
```

Code i have tried:

```
var allOrangeJuiceByClass = document.getElementsByClassName('u-dt');
var result = "document.getElements`enter code here`ByClassName('u-dt')";
for (var i = 0, len = allOrangeJuiceByClass.length|0; i < len; i = i+1|0) {
  result += "\n  " + allOrangeJuiceByClass[i].textContent;
}
```

Output:

```
20 minutes ago
38 minutes ago
```

Comment: Why a loop if you only want one element? And why those `|0` in the loop?

Comment: Without loop it doesn't iterate through class,  doesn't select the class 'u-dt' do you have code which doesn't work without loop

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = "";
[...document.querySelectorAll('time')].forEach(function(ele){
if(!ele.classList.contains("latestDate")){
    result += ele.innerText + "\n";
}
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<time class="u-dt" dir="auto" datetime="2020-01-18T11:04:03+0530" data-time="1579325643" data-date-string="Jan 18, 2020" data-time-string="11:04 AM" title="Jan 18, 2020 at 11:04 AM">20 minutes ago</time>
<time class="latestDate u-dt" dir="auto" datetime="2020-01-18T10:47:10+0530" data-time="1579324630" data-date-string="Jan 18, 2020" data-time-string="10:47 AM" title="Jan 18, 2020 at 10:47 AM">38 minutes ago</time>
```